# how to replace email domain name

Tags: regex, oracle, plsql, sql-update, oracle10g

Im trying to write a procedure that updates the domain of an email (example: converting Email123@gmail.com into Email123@hotmail.com when i pass 2 strings gmail.com and hotmail.com) while having a cursor in my procedure

```
create of replace procedure pr_update_email
(Old_Email Varchar2, New_Email Varchar2)
    As
    V_OldDomain Varchar2(50);
      Cursor C_Domains IS Select Email_Address
                From Customer
                where Email_Address Like '%@'||Old_Email;       
          Begin
          Open C_Domains;
          Fetch C_Domains INTO V_OldDomain; 
          While C_Domains %Found loop
                    Update Customer
                    Set Email_Address = regexp_replace(Email_Address, '^(.*@.*)'||Old_Email||'\1'||New_Email)
                    WHERE Email_Address LIKE V_OldDomain;   
          Fetch C_Domains into New_Email;
          End Loop;
  Close C_Domains;
End pr_update_email;
/
Show Errors;
```

getting errors:
 19/11    PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

19/32    PLS-00403: expression'NEW_EMAIL' cannot be used as an INTO-target of a
   SELECT/FETCH statement

Answer (score 0):

Why you are using the `cursor`? It can be handled using simple `update` statement.

Your procedure should look like this:

```
create procedure pr_update_email (p_oldemail in varchar2,
                       p_newemail in varchar2)
As
Begin

UPDATE BROKER
SET
    EMAIL_ADDRESS = REPLACE(EMAIL_ADDRESS, p_oldemail, p_newemail)
WHERE
    REGEXP_LIKE ( EMAIL_ADDRESS,'.*@'|| p_oldemail|| '$' );

Commit;

End;
/
```

Or if you really want to use the loop then

```
create of replace procedure pr_update_email
(Old_Email Varchar2, New_Email Varchar2)
    As
    Begin
          For i in (Select Email_Address
                From Customer
                where Email_Address Like '%@'||Old_Email) loop

             Update Customer
                Set Email_Address = Replace(Email_Address, old_email, new_email)
              WHERE Email_Address = i.Email_Address;   
          End Loop;
  Commit;
End pr_update_email;
/
```

To call this procedure, you need to pass both the domain as following:

```
Begin
pr_update_email('gmail.com', 'hotmail.com');
End;
/
```

And Yes, Issue in your code is following line:

```
Fetch C_Domains into New_Email;
```

`New_Email` is an input parameter and you can not assign any value to the input parameter.

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

You can directly update without creating a `Stored Procedure` but by using `Regexp_Replace()` and `Instr()` Functions :

```
SQL> Update Customer 
        Set Email_Address = Regexp_Replace(Email_Address,'(.*)@[gmail]+.(.*)','\1@hotmail.\2')
      Where Instr(Email_Address,'@gmail.') > 0;
SQL> Commit;
```

If you want to create a generic structure in order to be able to use for such other cases also, then transfer the above `Update` statement as :

```
SQL> Create Or Replace Procedure pr_update_email(Old_Email Varchar2, New_Email Varchar2) As
Begin
    Update Customer
       Set Email_Address = Regexp_Replace(Email_Address,'(.*)@['||Old_Email||']+.(.*)','\1@'||New_Email||'.\2')
     Where Instr(Email_Address,'@'||Old_Email||'.')>0 ;

End;
/
SQL> Begin
   pr_update_email('gmail','hotmail');
End;
/
SQL> Commit;
```